# Eventbrite in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eventbrite

I'm using eventbrite/eventbrite-sdk-javascript for my project. Everything is working fine but the response is giving me back only 50 events

```
Object
```

events
:
(50) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
pagination
:
{object_count: 58205, page_number: 1, page_size: 50, page_count: 200, has_more_items: true}

How can I see all events?

Comment: How does your request looks like? Eventbrite's API has pagination as you can see in page_number, page_size properties.

Comment: My request looks like this --- 
 sdk.request(`/events/search/?expand=venue`)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
               }
Just I need all events at once to be able to search all events

Comment: I don't think you can get all 58205 events in one page, [as described here](https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/api_overview/pagination/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The responses when fetching events using eventbrite's api are paginated, with a max of 50 results per page and a max of 200 pages. What you did was fetch the first (let's call it n) page. Now you have to call the api once more, and provide the page=n+1. This will give you the next 50 events.
Hope this helps!